# How to call an overloaded java function from JRuby with an array parameter

Tags: java, parameters, jruby

I have a java class with an overloaded method like the following one:

```
public class Main {
  public void print(Object o) {
      System.out.println("printing object...");
  }

  public void print(Object[][] o) {
      System.out.println("printing matrix...");
  }
}
```

Now I want jruby to call `print(Object[][])` if the argument is a two dimensional array, like so:

```
m = Main.new
m.print 123
m.print [[1,2],[3]]
```

But the output is:

```
printing object...
printing object...
```

So jruby is calling `print(Object)` ignoring the array type. How can I make jruby call `print(Object[][])`?

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle the ambiguity the java functions can be called like this:

```
m.java_send :print, [java.lang.Object], [["test"]]      #=> printing object...
m.java_send :print, [java.lang.Object[][]], [["test"]]  #=> printing matrix...
```

The first argument is the method name as a symbol, second argument is an array of argument types and all following arguments are passed to the java function.

source: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#calling-masked-or-unreachable-java-methods-with-java_send